# session variable won't display

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I am trying to send POST data into a SESSION variable

$_SESSION['plan'] = $_POST['plan']

info.php show that sessions are loaded.
browser -> inspect element appears to show sessions initialized but no key => values.

But I cannot get the session value to display.
no errors in apache logs.

main dynamic frame:

## cat index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="nav">
        <ul>
              BLAH
        </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">
        <?php
                $pages_dir = 'pages';
                if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
                        $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
                        unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);
                        $p=$_GET['p'];
                        if(in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)){
                                include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
                        }else {
                                echo 'Sorry, page not found.';
                        }
                }else{
                        include($pages_dir.'/home.inc.php');
                }
        ?>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

User form page:

## cat pages/payment.inc.php

```
<?php
//$_SESSION['plan'] = $_POST['plan'];
?>
<div id="content_pay">

<form action="pages/scheckout.php" method="post">
        <div>

                <input type="radio" id="plan1" name="plan" value="2500"> Beta membership <br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="plan2" name="plan" value="3500"> VIP membership <br><br>

                <label for="plan"> If you would like to pay another amount, enter the amount here:</label>
                <input type="text" id="plan3" name="plan" />
                <br>
                <label for="invoice_num"> Enter the invoice number here:</label>
                <input type="text" name="invoice_num" /> <br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </div>
</form>


</div>
```

---

Basically this page is here just to capture the POST and assign it to SESSION then redirect with SESSION loaded:

## cat pages/scheckout.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['plan'] = $_POST['plan'];

//needed to prevent weird race conditions
session_write_close();
header("location: ../index.php?p=scheckout");
die();

echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION['plan'];

?>
```

---

Where is goes to:

## cat pages/scheckout.inc.php

```
<?php

require_once('pages/sconfig.php');

?>

<div id="content_pay">

<form action="pages/scharge.php" method="post">
        <div>


        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
                myElem.setAttribute('data-amount', <?php $_SESSION['plan']; ?>);
                myElem.setAttribute('data-description', <?php $_SESSION['plan']; ?>); >
        </script>
        </div>

</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<?php
echo $_SESSION['plan'];
?>
```

How do I get SESSIONS loaded from POST to display?

Comment: Is the session started inside all pages sessions?

Comment: as soon as I put the radio buttons in one form and the text input into another form, I was able to post and retrieve the data correctly. I never found a way to make one button operate both elements. I just suffered with two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start the session only once, before the html output. A session stays open until you use `session_destroy` or `unset` the `$_SESSION` variable, or close the browser. I suggest you, to delete all `session_start`s except the one in the index.php.

Comment: index.php is a frame, and within that frame is $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0); and that's where all of my .inc.php files are. They are drawn in dynamically. So index.php cascades the session_start() over all .inc.php pages. No errors in logs about (session already started) unless I try and add session_start to a .inc.php page

Answer (score 0):

you use SESSION['plan'], but should use echo SESSION['plan']

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
            myElem.setAttribute('data-amount', <?php echo($_SESSION['plan']); ?>);
            myElem.setAttribute('data-description', <?php echo($_SESSION['plan']); ?>); >
    </script>
```

Comment: same issue after change. I get an error in logs  ->  Undefined index: PLAN in pages/scheckout.inc.php on line 35